# Can we use PDFKit framework for iPad?

Tags: iphone

i'm trying to launch a webView by clicking a URL link in a Pdf file.... but i'm unable to do it.... one of the forum member asked me to use PDFKit but it works only in MAc OS 10.0 and above. Where as i'm trying to create my APP in SDK 3.2.. please send the sample code if possible....

Answer (score 1):

No in iOS 4.2 there is no PDFKit framework available (see the document "iOS Technology Overview").  In UIKit and in the QuartzCore.framework are same functions for working with PDF's.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11 the answer to this question is now yes.